# ¿Cómo modificar las clases de un modelo "dbml" para converitrlo en un "edmx"?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, dbml

Tengo un proyecto MVC con VS2012 que se conecta a una BD SQL Server 2012 con un modelo de objetos LINQ to SQL (`dbml`). Me recomendaron usar Entity Framework y como ya tengo el modelo de datos físico quiero que sea *Database First*. ¿Existe alguna manera rápida de modificar mis clases que consumen el modelo `dbml` para que consuma el modelo edmx?

Answer (score 1):

Debo comentarte que entre ambas tecnologias no hay compatibilidad, si quizas algunas similitudes, pero no tantas como para que el pasaje de una a otra se completamente transparente.

[EF Designer para una base de datos existente (Database First)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/data/ee712907)

Cuando trabajas con DataBase First en Entity Framework este crea un modelo visual de las tablas de la db y como mapean, por ese lado es similar a linq to sql, pero el codigo que genere seguramente difiera y debas adapatar el desarrollo al uso del nuevo contexto.

No se si estas trabajando con entidades POCO separandolas en capas, o si esta todo el codigo en un mismo proyecto, porque esto tambien puede generar diferencias.

Si el modelo es el mismo las clases no deberia verse afectadas, apunto a las clases que definen el dominio de tu aplicacion, lo que si se modificara es el contexto y los metodos que usa cada libreria.

Simplemente deberias quitar el .dbml y agregar el .edmx corrigiendo el codigo alli donde se genere un error por las nuevos metodo que agrega entity framework

Nota: Recomiendo realices un backup de la solucion antes de emprender el cambio de un modelo de persistencia a otro, por si tienes que volver atras, un simple zip de la carpeta donde tienes el sln alcanza.